# How to install AWS CLI for root user on Centos 7 - /usr/local/bin not in PATH for root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos, command-line-interface, root

When I install the AWS CLI for the root user on CENTOS 7, it installs it to /usr/local/bin as with other users.  Problem is though, /usr/local/bin isn't in $PATH for the root user.  At first I thought this was a bug in CENTOS, one that has been around for a very long time, but it's also possible its for reasons of security, I don't know.

What would be best practice then to install the AWS CLI for the root user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement Chris'es answer, you can install the [AWS CLI v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install) in a folder visible to root, such as `/usr/local/sbin` as follows:

```
sudo yum install unzip
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install --bin-dir /usr/local/sbin
```

then confirm with:

```
aws --version
```

which should produce:

```
aws-cli/2.0.44 Python/3.7.3 Linux/3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 exe/x86_64.centos.7
```

Answer (score 1):

This [appears to a bug logged](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5707) in CentOS since 2012 in CentOS 6 but as of yet has not been fixed.

Regarding running AWS CLI as root, you can still run it by running `/usr/local/bin/aws` although I get that this is not ideal. Additionally you should try to avoid running AWS CLI as root if possible, instead run it as a named user.

According to the documentation you can use either `--bin-dir` or `-b` to specify a different bin directory so you could check a path that both root and named users have in their `$PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

```
sudo ./aws/install --bin-dir /usr/bin
```